# How to generate a list of 4 values that adds up to 1 in Python?

Tags: python, math, permutation

I'm trying to generate a complete list of 4 values that adds up to 1. Each value can be 10% increment.

For example,

These are valid lists

```
[0, 0, 0, 1]
[0.1, 0.8, 0.1, 0]
[0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.4]
```

These are invalid lists

```
[1, 0.1, 0, 0]
[0.5, 0.5, 0.1, 0]
```

I believe the permutation would be

`10!/6!` I could be wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Stefan's solution is nicer, however, you can also do this using list comprehension and the `itertools` library:

```
import itertools
perm = [[x /10.0 for x in t] for t in itertools.product(range(11), repeat=4) if sum(t)==10]
```

Comment: Could use `product(range(11), repeat=4)` and `sum(element)`.

Comment: Thanks, that makes the code look a lot neater.

Answer (score 2):

This cuts the interval [0, 10] at three integers, giving you four subintervals whose lengths just need to be divided by 10.

```
>>> import itertools
>>> for a, b, c in itertools.combinations_with_replacement(range(11), 3):
        print([a/10, (b-a)/10, (c-b)/10, (10-c)/10])

[0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0]
[0.0, 0.0, 0.1, 0.9]
[0.0, 0.0, 0.2, 0.8]
[0.0, 0.0, 0.3, 0.7]
[0.0, 0.0, 0.4, 0.6]
[0.0, 0.0, 0.5, 0.5]
[0.0, 0.0, 0.6, 0.4]
[0.0, 0.0, 0.7, 0.3]
[0.0, 0.0, 0.8, 0.2]
[0.0, 0.0, 0.9, 0.1]
[0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0]
[0.0, 0.1, 0.0, 0.9]
[0.0, 0.1, 0.1, 0.8]
[0.0, 0.1, 0.2, 0.7]
[0.0, 0.1, 0.3, 0.6]
...
...
...
[0.7, 0.2, 0.0, 0.1]
[0.7, 0.2, 0.1, 0.0]
[0.7, 0.3, 0.0, 0.0]
[0.8, 0.0, 0.0, 0.2]
[0.8, 0.0, 0.1, 0.1]
[0.8, 0.0, 0.2, 0.0]
[0.8, 0.1, 0.0, 0.1]
[0.8, 0.1, 0.1, 0.0]
[0.8, 0.2, 0.0, 0.0]
[0.9, 0.0, 0.0, 0.1]
[0.9, 0.0, 0.1, 0.0]
[0.9, 0.1, 0.0, 0.0]
[1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]
```

Or more general (just replace 3 by the number of cuts you want):

```
>>> for cuts in itertools.combinations_with_replacement(range(11), 3):
        print([(b-a)/10 for a, b in zip((0,) + cuts, cuts + (10,))])
```

Answer (score 1):

What you need is called an [integer partition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_%28number_theory%29). A web search for that term should turn up a lot of hits. An integer partition of n of length m is just a list of m positive integers which add up to n.

Once you have an integer partition of 10 of length 4, you can just divide the integers by 10 to get increments of 0.1 and a sum of 1.

EDIT: I see that the list could be less than 4 items (some elements could be zero). So you are looking for integer partitions of length <= 4 (not length == 4).

Comment: Thanks for the answer.